# Split a 3D numpy array into smaller 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D np.array

```py
arr = np.array([ 
                [ [0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ],
                [ [0, 255, 0], [255, 40, 0], [0, 0, 200], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [120, 51, 58] ],
                [ [0, 0, 30], [0, 40, 0], [200, 100, 20], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [13, 78, 84], ],
                [ [0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ],
                [ [0, 255, 0], [255, 40, 0], [0, 0, 200], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [120, 51, 58] ],
                [ [0, 0, 30], [0, 40, 0], [200, 100, 20], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [13, 78, 84], ],
                [ [0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ],
                [ [0, 255, 0], [255, 40, 0], [0, 0, 200], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [120, 51, 58] ],
                [ [0, 0, 30], [0, 40, 0], [200, 100, 20], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [13, 78, 84], ],
              ])
```

And I need to split it to 3x2x3 3D arrays

```py
[ [0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30],    [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3],             [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ],
[ [0, 255, 0],  [255, 40, 0],      [0, 0, 200], [7, 8, 9],           [10, 11, 12], [120, 51, 58] ],
[ [0, 0, 30],   [0, 40, 0],        [200, 100, 20], [12, 13, 14],     [15, 16, 17], [13, 78, 84], ],

[ [0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30],    [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3],             [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ],
[ [0, 255, 0],  [255, 40, 0],      [0, 0, 200], [7, 8, 9],           [10, 11, 12], [120, 51, 58] ],
[ [0, 0, 30],   [0, 40, 0],        [200, 100, 20], [12, 13, 14],     [15, 16, 17], [13, 78, 84], ],

[ [0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30],    [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3],             [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ],
[ [0, 255, 0],  [255, 40, 0],      [0, 0, 200], [7, 8, 9],           [10, 11, 12], [120, 51, 58] ],
[ [0, 0, 30],   [0, 40, 0],        [200, 100, 20], [12, 13, 14],     [15, 16, 17], [13, 78, 84], ],
```

to get a 4D array with these 3D blocks I've selected by spaces. Zero element must be

```py
[ 
    [[0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30]],
    [[0, 255, 0], [255, 40, 0]],
    [[0, 0, 30], [0, 40, 0]] 
]
```

and so on.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429900/split-a-3d-numpy-array-into-3d-blocks) question but still don't undersatand how to do this (Why we need to reshape, transpose and reshape again and what a magical numbers in `transpose()`). I could try to write my own function but I want to know how to do it native way.

Comment: Is this what you want `arr.reshape(9,2,3,3)`?

Comment: @yatu, no I want 3D arrays instead vectors

Comment: Do you want a 4D array or a list of 3D arrays?

Comment: @Valentino, 4D nympy array

Comment: It looks to me like your desired output is 5D with shape (3,3,3,2,3) ?

Comment: Why didn't you provide the source shape, and desired shape?  It's a pain to count brackets when dimensions are 3 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape and transpose it

```
arr.reshape(3, 3, 3, 2, 3).transpose(2, 0, 1, 3, 4)
# array([[[[[  0, 205,  25],
#           [210, 150,  30]],
# 
#          [[  0, 255,   0],
#           [255,  40,   0]],
# 
#          [[  0,   0,  30],
#           [  0,  40,   0]]],
# 
# 
#         [[[  0, 205,  25],
#           [210, 150,  30]],
# 
#          [[  0, 255,   0],
#           [255,  40,   0]],
# 
#          [[  0,   0,  30],
#           [  0,  40,   0]]],
# 
# 
# ...
```

Comment: Would you explain these numbers?

Comment: They're the numbers you gave in your question. `-1` means "infer this value from the remaining numbers"

Comment: Specifically, reading the linked documentation for `reshape`, it is "The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions."

Comment: I need some another order. Zero element must be ```[ [[0, 205, 25], [210, 150, 30]], [[0, 255, 0],  [255, 40, 0]], [[0, 0, 30],   [0, 40, 0]] ]

Comment: @NilsWerner, such a strange thing. I have another outpit 
[[[  0 205  25]
  [210 150  30]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  1   2   3]
  [  4   5   6]
  [  7   8   9]]

 [[  0 255   0]
  [255  40   0]
  [  0   0 200]
  [  7   8   9]
  [ 10  11  12]
  [120  51  58]] ...]

Comment: There must be something wrong in your reshaping operation, axis `-2` has a size of `6`, but my call to `reshape()` has no `6`.

Comment: @NilsWerner found out that I need to use arr = arr.reshape(3, 3, 3, 2, 3).transpose(2, 0, 1, 3, 4). numpy==1.17.2

Comment: That's **exactly** the solution I posted?